# Unicode symbols when creating DocumentTermMatrix

Tags: r, unicode, text-mining, tm

I am using the TM package from CRAN in R. I have problems creating a DocumentTermMatrix based on a Corpus. The problems is when I create a TermDocumentMatrix based on an UTF-8 corpus then some words turn into a unicode symbols.

```
corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(vector_with_texts_in_several_languages, encoding = "UTF-8"))
tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(corpus, control=list(weighting=weightTfIdf))
print(Terms(tdm)[1:3])
```

Returns:

```
[1] "<U+03BB>a<U+03B3><U+03AF>a"
[2] "<U+03C1><U+03AE>fa<U+03BD><U+03BF><U+03C2>" 
[3] "<U+03C1><U+03AF>p<U+03BF><U+03C5>"
```

If I manually inspect the corpus then I see correct output.

```
print(corpus[[1]])
```

Returns:

```
квартира на кутузовском
```

Does anyone know how I can get a TermDocumentMatrix with correct Terms? Or is there a way to convert these unicode symbols into 'readable' output again?

Note: print(Terms(tdm)) does NOT contain words from print(corpus[[1]])

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the encoding works for the first step, you can try to inspect the first element of the corpus:

```
 corpus[[1]]
```